# SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path webapps/FT.keystore due to signed overrun, bytes = 128 on TomCat 6 startup

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

I am trying to configure Tomcat so as to accept HTTPS requests. The problem is that when I start Tomcat, I have the following exception :

**SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path webapps/FT.keystore due to signed overrun, bytes = 128**

I have already created the keystore FT.keystore and placed it in webapps/ directory.

Here is the configuration I use for the HTTPS connector 
(The *xxx* are only to keep informations private)

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="webapps/xxx.keystore" keystorePass="xxxx"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Could any one help me solve this problem? I used keytool ($JAVA_HOME/bin) to generate my keystore and the RSA algorithm.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your connector configuration looks good, so I suspect there's something wrong with the generated keystore. Are you sure you generated it as instructed in [Tomcat 6 SSL Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)? The command should look like this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

(Pay attention to the `-alias tomcat` parameter - I found some references which indicate that leaving it out would cause the "signed overrun" problem you're having.)

Comment: Thank you for answering Tommi. Actually I did exactly like explained in [Tomcat 6 SSL Configuration HOW-TO][1]. But when I removed the parameter `-alias tomcat`, I got a new exception : 
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate`.
When I try adding the parameter `-storetype pkcs12`, I have this exception:
`keytool error: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.`
Am I missing something else?
Thank you in advance